# Issue with network drives freespace check - Powershell script

Tags: windows, batch, powershell

I have a batch file which deletes some files from the network drives and then calls a powershell script. The powershell script gets the space details of all the network drives, and send out a mail. Below is the command used to getting the space details :

```
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "ABCD001" -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 4";
    $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID;
    foreach($disk in $disks)
    {
        $totalSpaceGB = [Math]::Round([float]$disk.Size / 1073741824, 2);
        $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round([float]$disk.FreeSpace / 1073741824, 2);
        $disk, 'TotalSize = ', $totalSpaceGB + " Gb", 'FreeSpace = ', $freeSpaceGB + " Gb", $disk.ProviderName -join '  ' | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Append -Width 200;
    }
```

Below is the command used to get the space details of the local drives:

```
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3";
```

The issue is, when I run this batch file manually, it runs fine. But when scheduled or run from the Task Scheduler, the result for the network drives comes as below:

```
TotalSize =     0    Gb FreeSpace =     0    Gb
```

Looks like it is unable to connect to the network drives. As I said earlier, when I go in and run the batch script manually, it returns the desired result.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler needs to know to run the script as an administrator.